# compiling VS2008 aspnet project causes windows to thrash and freeze

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2008

I recently got a new laptop with an SSD. Expected faster performance (and boot is very fast) but **PROBLEM**: when I build my VS 2008 asp.net application, windows freezes, appears to be thrashing.

**SYMPTOMS**: It appears exactly as if i was using too much memory - switching to other programs take a few seconds as if windows was loading the program from page file. Switching to other programs makes my compile run for ever as well. Drive usage light lights up solid. Using resource monitor, I see the asp.net temporary files having rather long 1500ms access time while this is happening.

-I disabled my antivirus
-disabled indexing
-checked memory very well for faults
-checked my harddrive very well for faults
- I tried to close all unnecessary programs

ALL to no effect...

My other laptop (t41, this one is t410) with a regular HD did not have this issue. I tried and read about it like crazy, no luck!

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!!

PerfMon while compiling (and using skype, nothing else)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like an issue with when you moved to the SSD.  How did you move your OS to the SSD? Image or reinstall?  What kind of SSD is it?

Comment: @SURFASB, no, not an image. Laptop came with window7 32 bit, I upgraded to 64 bit. reinstalled everything else from scratch. 

SSD is SAMSUNG MMCRE28G8MXP-0VB

And thanks for reply!

Comment: I assume it only does this during VS2008?

Comment: well, i think the problem is most visible during the build but i see this in general with a lot of disk activity. lots of disk activity, (but throughput is small), yet window is very unresponsive. exactly as if there were a lot of pagefile access. I read a lot of post on supersuer that suggest faulty SSD but I ran all test I can think of and all is well - lenovo will not warrant my drive in this case :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, to convince the support staff, you'll need to gather data.  Fire up Performance monitor.  You can type in `perfmon.exe` at the Run box.  The counters you'll want to add are the following

- Avg Disk sec/Read
- Avg Disk sec/Transfer
- Avg Disk sec/Write
- Avg Disk Byte/Read
- Avg Disk Byte/Write
- Avg Disk Byte/Transfer

These are the important ones. *AvgDiskSec* tells you how many seconds each Read/Writes request is taking. *AvgDiskByte* is how much data is in each transfer.

This will give us a respectable look at your disk performance. These are the same counters you would use to diagnoses disk performance on a database's SAN.  Of course on a large database, the transfer times are ideally in the microseconds.  On a SSD, you should get similar times also. If it goes above ten milliseconds a transfer, then either you are hitting your caps or you are just experiencing some weird weird access times.  Hopefully these logs will help.

Comment: I added the counters as you asked to the original post. dont have experience reading them but they dont look good to me :(

While Compiling (when those counters where captured) the computer is very unresponsive. takes 30 seconds for task manager to come up

thanks for your help surfasb!!

Comment: Don't bring up Task manager.  That actually makes it WORSE!! Run through your normal routine and then view the log file afterwards.  If anything, upload it to the Microsoft forums.  The VS support team at one point worked with me for six hours straight to stomp out a bug. At least exhaust all your options.

Comment: But you are right, something is fishy. Those disk operations are taking WAY too long to complete.  I'd take the drive back. Plus those disk transfers aren't that big, so we can rule out bandwidth.

Comment: Crap I forgot you can't take it back. I'd hold on to these graphs.  Maybe you can tell Lenovo that they are smoking crack.  I'd fire up another program to to make more graphs.  Anything that makes a lot of reads, like a search index, or antivirus scans.